# Iterate and open new browser pages causes StaleElementReferenceException

Tags: selenium, robotframework

I have a very simple script that find all HREF in a page and iterate and logs it:

```
Photo search scroll
    Go To   https://xxx
    ${elements}=    Get WebElements     xpath://a[contains(@href,'photo')]
    FOR    ${element}    IN    @{elements}
        Log    ${element.get_attribute('href')}
    END
```

It works perfectly fine.
As I need to open a new browser for each of HREF I added Selenium Browser command:

```
Photo search scroll
    Go To   https://xxx
    ${elements}=    Get WebElements     xpath://a[contains(@href,'photo')]
    FOR    ${element}    IN    @{elements}
        Log    ${element.get_attribute('href')}
        Go To      ${element.get_attribute('href')}
        sleep   2s
        Capture Page Screenshot
        Go Back
    END
```

I always get this error after first iteration:

```
Resolving variable '${element.get_attribute('href')}' failed: StaleElementReferenceException: Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document
  (Session info: chrome=86.0.4240.111)
```

I'm unable to figure out why this happen.
Any help/comments is appreciated.
Many Thanks

###UPDATE
I've created a list varible and addedd additional loop:

```
@{hrefs} =  Create List
    FOR    ${element}    IN    @{elements}
        Log    ${element.get_attribute('href')}
        Append To List  ${hrefs}        ${element.get_attribute('href')}  
    END

    FOR     ${href}     IN      @{hrefs}
        Go To           ${href}
        sleep  2s
        Capture Page Screenshot
    END
```

now I obtain this error code:

```
Opening url 'Create List'   
20:08:36.739    FAIL    InvalidArgumentException: Message: invalid argument
  (Session info: chrome=86.0.4240.111)
```

[image]

Comment: I don't replicate the error in your update, it works as expected; which line logs the `InvalidArgumentException`? And what's the value of the argument you're passing at that moment?

Comment: Just added the screenshot

Comment: The first element in your `${hrefs}` list variable is literally the string `"Create List"`; I don't know how you set it (in the loop before this one), but that's not a valid url.

Comment: indeed it was a stupid error: @{hrefs} = Create List Now sorted thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> why this happens

Because when you called `Get WebElements` you got references to objects in the current page & session; the browser also keeps the same references, to the current DOM elements.

When you go to a different page and then back, this is a different page for the browser. Visually it is the same; its html is the same.
But for the browser, this is a different page than the one you started from; its internal references to the elements in it are different (the "map" it builds for the page you're browsing). In the same time, you request from the browser to give you an object by a reference. But the browser doesn't have it - those objects are not called the same for it, the references are different. You've got a stale (expired, not valid, old) reference, not pointing to any DOM object it has in its "map". `StaleElementReferenceException` :)

The solution - open the target links in a new tab; thus your page will not refresh, and the references will be valid.
Or better, get all links, and open them in a new loop.

Comment: Thx, what is not clear to me is this part=> ${elements}=    Get WebElements     xpath://a[contains(@href,'photo')] => it's not a static variable containing the link from page opened before? why loop is failing? thx

Comment: It does become a static variable - what you get as returned value is a list of references. E.g. all of them are evaluated once, when you called the keyword; versus a lazy evaluation (on each loop cycle) as you might think.

Comment: I've changed the code as per suggested (get links than iterate apart), and still does not seems to work. If I look to the log all links are absolutely valid ones